# 2 Table Rows per 1 Database Table Row

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm working on a table in *iReport* designer where I pull in info from a database. As of right now, I have it so that one row of the table corresponds to one row in the database.

How can I make it so that one entry in the database can take up two rows. The first row would have 4 columns corresponding to a field in the database. The second row would have 1 column the same length as the 4 above columns combined and also correspond to one field. When editing an *iReport* designer table, there doesn't seem to be an option to add more rows, only columns.

Answer (score 0):

I found a much easier workaround. I created a one column table, then dragged and dropped static text and fields in certain spots to make the report look like it had multiple columns.